# Frequency of child records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with a parent-child association in rails and would like to count the number of times a specific child belongs to a parent. If for example: Parent1.children = [A,B,C] and Parent2.children = [B,D], I would like to get the count of each child record [A => 1, B => 2, C => 1, D => 1]. How should one construct the query?

Comment: First put all the child in an array,then use `each_with_object` method in Ruby,having `Hash.new(0)` as the internal hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a hash where each key is the id of a child and each value the count of its parents:

```
Children.joins(:parents).group('childrens.id').count
```

This will give you an array of the childrens where each child has been initialized with the attr `parents_count` so you can then build a hash (`child => parents_count`)with it:

```
childrens_with_count = Children.joins(:parents).group('childrens.id').select('childrens.*, COUNT(*) AS parents_count')
childrens_with_count.map { |child| { child => child.parents_count } }
#=> [#<Child id=1 ...> => 2, #<Child id=2...> => 10 ... ]
```

Comment: Inner join is not a good fit here. The children which have no parents will be missing from the output.

Comment: @DNNX You are right. I have assumed that a child with no parents is not a child.

Comment: If I have a multidimensional array grouped by parent: [[A,B,C],[B,D]], how would one proceed from there?

Comment: @graphmeter, `gem install facets`, `requre 'facets/enumerable/frequency'; [[A, B, C], [B, D]].flatten.frequency` will output `{A => 1, B => 2, C => 1, D => 2}`

Comment: @PabloB. sir, this is sad :(

Comment: @graphmeter `multi_array.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |child, children_count| children_count[child] += 1 }`

Comment: @DNNX I will look into the facets gem, but I rather not add any additional gems for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way, but may not be the most efficient from an SQL query perspective:

```
child_counts = Parent.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |p, counts| p.children.each { |c| counts[c.id] += 1 } }
```

The resulting hash, `child_counts`, gives counts per child id (child id is the hash key).

Comment: Thanks, seems to work..is there a more efficient way to do this query?

Comment: Yes, there is. See another answer.

Comment: @graphmeter check Pablo B's answer. It's more "SQL concious"